# When and how to start independence in Colonization?

Tags: civilization-4, civ-4-colonization

I didn't understood when and eventually how can I start independence in Colonization. Can you explain?

Comment: This has been tagged Civ-4, that seems to be the wrong game. Was a different tag intended?

Comment: The latest colonization is actually named 'Civilization 4: Colonization"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Civ Fanatics Colonization FAQ](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=305049):

> What are the requirements for
>   declaring independence?
>
> The only requirement for starting a
>   revolution and proclaiming
>   independence is reaching a level of
>   50% for "Rebel Sentiment". Rebel
>   Sentiment measures production of
>   Liberty Bells, somewhat like Culture
>   in Civ4, across the empire as a whole.

At this point the European King sends the 'Royal Expeditionary Force' to stop you.  You now have to fight a war of independence.  As such you want to be in a position where you have enough resources (guns, horses etc.) to fight a prolonged war.

Again from the [Civ Fanatics Colonization FAQ](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=305049):

> How can I possibly defeat the King's
>   forces?
>
> ...you cannot build stronger units
>   than the European King. Thus, you must
>   be patient and plan for the long-term:
>   since the REF comes in waves, make
>   sure to take advantage of lulls in
>   fighting to replenish your resource
>   stocks. Also, do not waste too many
>   units trying to go on the offensive --
>   often, it is more efficient to engage
>   in a war of attrition, using the
>   settlements' defenses and terrain
>   defensive bonuses to wear down the
>   REF. The timing of your declaration of
>   independence is also important. Be
>   certain that when you declare your
>   revolution, you have enough key
>   resources, like Tools, Guns, and
>   Horses, to convert colonists to
>   soldiers in case of an emergency.
>   Having a homegrown Gun industry would
>   also be beneficial and reduce
>   dependence on Europe.